# ERROR: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
print("BOT: My name is Stark. Let's have a conversation! Also, if you want to exit any time, just type Bye!")
```

This is just a simple code having a bunch of if-else statements, in which I am taking input from a user and trying to give some logical response to queries.

```
while(flag==True):
    user_response = input() 
    user_response=user_response.lower() 
    if(user_response !='bye'): 
        if(user_response == 'thanks' or user_response == 'thank you'):
            flag=False
            print("BOT: You are welcome..") 
        else: 
            if(greet(user_response) !=None):
                    print("BOT: "+greet (user_response )) 
            else:
                    sent_tokens.append(user_response) 
                    word_tokens = word_tokens + nltk.word_tokenize(user_response)
                    final_words=list(set(word_tokens))
                    print("BOT:","end = ")
                    print(response(user_response))//HERE ERROR IS COMING
                    sent_tokens.remove(user_response)
```

```
else:
        flag = false
        print("BOT: GoodBye! See you Later")'''
```

I am getting above mentioned error for the commented line, but am not able to solve it. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

what is **response** in your code,is you getting value from request or httpx then you can't pass value to it. But you want to returning value as endpoint then you should define response with **response.mimetype = "text/plain"**